# Position button always at the same position if content is scrollable

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="row table-filter flex-container show"> //This has absolute position because i need to show this on top of a table its a filter which open on click of table header
  <div class="uniqueTable">
    <div class="row tablescroll"> // Here im displaying filter values which is not fix it can be 10 or more than 100
    </div>
    <div class="btn-wrapper"></div> //these are button which i want to display at fixed position suppose content increase so i want to make it fix to same position it should not scroll with content
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css

```
.table-filter{
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: -68px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 25em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 11em;
}
```

parent div table filter has absolute position and if content is large scroller is there but i want my btn-wrapper to stay at same position if scroller is there

Comment: you may use css `position:fixed;` for your button.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: fixed` for the button may be what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn_wrapper { position: fixed; top: 100px;}
```

Change value of top as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are correct. `position:fixed;` is the best way to go. I've made a quick change to your code in the codepen here: https://codepen.io/Robhern135/pen/YEwByR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.table-filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 68px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 11em;
}

.uniqueTable {
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="" class="row table-filter flex-container show">
  Header
  <div class="uniqueTable">
    <div class="row tablescroll">
      Filter<br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br> Filter
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-wrapper"> <button>Save</button><button>Edit</button> </div>
</div>
```

Using `position:fixed` will position the element relative to the screen. I guess you are looking for elements to be fixed relative to parent `.table` element